# Pros and cons of the following Parsing methods?

Tags: javascript, python, compilation

I'm thinking of making a Python-JavaScript converter/compile. I've been wondering about the pros and cons of the following methods to parse the Pythonic code, into JavaScript equivalent.

1. Working with the output of `ast.dump(ast.parse(code))`
2. Working with tokens.

I've been trying weigh the pros and cons of these methods, but well I'm unable to think of any major one, as I've never used them..
So, Basically could someone help me by telling me what the pros and cons of the two methods I've mentioned above are?
Also, if there is something better that I can use for this purpose, notify me about it..

PS: I'll be using Python to write the converter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big con of tokens: You'll have to parse, and this is both unnecessary and nontrivial.

Big con of `ast.dump(ast.parse(code))`: It's pointlessly stupid. `ast.parse` gives you a perfectly good AST, structured in an appropriate data structure. `ast.dump` gives you a string representation of that data structure, so you'd have to parse *that* to get back what `ast.parse` already gave you!

Leaving out `ast.dump` and using the AST from `ast.parse`, there are two big pros:

- You don't have to worry about parsing Python code at all (and doing so is moderately complex).
- ASTs are really the minimum you need to look at for any compiler-ish project at this scale. While the `ast` AST may have some complexity you don't need (e.g. line information, or Python features you don't support), I assume that simplifying a Python AST to your custom AST is simpler than generating your custom AST from tokens.
- A minor benefit: There's already a visitor class built into `ast`, so you don't have to create one (a simple but somewhat boring task) for easy AST traversal.

Cons? Not so much. Go for `ast`, but don't be afraid to use *additional* data structures beyond that.

Comment: So use `ast`!! Thx.. Any cons?

Comment: As I said, it may have some fluff that gets in your way, so you may want to immediately turn the AST into a different, simpler AST.

Comment: I was thinking of using `ast.dump` as I wanted to parse a string, maybe implement some functions, and then evaluate the string..

Comment: Token have flexibility, I can have the user type `$`, for using jquery..

Comment: @Schoolboy Yes, although then you aren't parsing Python but a *dialect* of it, which would have been a useful piece of info to include in the question. Assuming you're using `tokenize`, you don't get unlimited flexibility either: `$` produces an "error" token (and I wouldn't be surprised if the next refactoring of the tokenizer turns it into an actual error), and indentation is checked during tokenizing. Of course, if you don't use `tokenize` and write your own lexer, you're facing even more work...